# (Java) "error: cannot find symbol" when compiling?

Tags: java, linux, class, compiler-errors

This is the first time I'm coding in Linux, I'm used with writing in Windows. So my problem: I have a map called `Train`, in there I have two classes: `Train.java` and `Lab1.java`.

When I try to compile(using `javac Train.java` in the terminal), I get no errors with one of the class, but with the other one I get this error:

```
Lab1.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
        Train trainThread2 = new Train(tsi, trackSemas, secondTSpeed, 2, true, tsispeed,8);
```

This code is from the `Lab1.java` class. It points at the `Train` and shows this error above, that it cannot find the symbol `Train`

I didn't find any information that helped me, so I'll try asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Lab1` depends on the class `Train` so you need to tell the path of the compiled `Train` class in its classpath. The easiest solution is to compile both at once:

```
javac Train.java Lab1.java
```